# jQuery: font-variation-settings based on cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to transform a variable font based on the position of the cursor. If the cursor has a `x` position of `0px`, the `wght` should be `200`, if the cusor position is at the right border of the page, the `wght` should be `800`. The transition has to be fluid.

This is my start:

```js
$(document).on("mouseover", function(e){
if(e.pageX <= 100)
{
$("div").css( "font-variation-settings", "'wght' 200" )
}
if(e.pageX >= 100)
{
$("div").css( "font-variation-settings", "'wght' 800" )
}
});
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
font-size: 5vw;
font-variation-settings: 'wght' 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli:wght@200..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div>Weight based on cursor position</div>
```

Who can help me? Would be very thankful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As smooth as possible :P

```js
$(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
  let factor = e.pageX / $(document).width();
  let wght = 200 + 600 * factor;
  
  $("div").css("font-variation-settings", "'wght' " + wght)
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli:wght@200..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div>Weight based on cursor position</div>
```

---

UPDATE: Added a delay to optimize it a bit.

```js
let enableHandler = true;

timer = window.setInterval(function() {
  enableHandler = true;
}, 50);

$(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (enableHandler) {
    let factor = e.pageX / $(document).width();
    let wght = 200 + 600 * factor;

    $("div").css("font-variation-settings", "'wght' " + wght)
    enableHandler = false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli:wght@200..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div>Weight based on cursor position</div>
```

Comment: Hello! I posted an additional question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866443/jquery-font-variation-settings-based-on-horizontal-and-vertical-cursor-position – I would be super happy if you could help with that as well :)